# How to detect lowercase letters in Python 3.2?

Tags: python, string, lowercase, letters

Okay, I'm not really getting the answers I was looking for so I'll try rewording this.  I need to know if there is a function that detects the lowercase letters in a string.  Say I started writing this program:

```
s = input('Type a word')
```

Would there be a function that lets me detect a lowercase letter within the string s?  Possibly ending up with assigning those letters to a different variable, or just printing the lowercase letters or number of lowercase letters.

While those would be what I would like to do with it I'm most interested in how to detect the presence of lowercase letters.  The simplest methods would be welcome, I am only in an introductory python course so my teacher wouldn't want to see complex solutions when I take my midterm.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you had a chance to go over the `str` documentation yet?

Comment: `filter(str.islower, 'MarMaLadE')`?

Comment: Do you need to support non-ascii letters? Do you care if solution treats Unicode codepoints and user-percieved characters the same e.g., if it looses diacritics for some letters?

Comment: @Blender: try `'u\u0308ü'`. Also `filter()` doesn't return a string for a string input in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression is probably the simplest way:

```
# Python 3 version

import re

txt = 'MarMaLadE'

# Replace uppercase with "" - an empty string
ltxt,n = re.subn(r'[A-Z]', "", txt) 

print("lower case letters:"," ".join(set(ltxt)))
print("number of lc letters:", n)
```

The use of `set` removes duplicate lowercase letters, you might not want that.  You might also want to consider which characters are uppercase, is `A-Z` sufficient?  See also the `re.LOCALE` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, keep in mind that python is wary of indentation. This is not a very good solution but it works.

```
def doWhatYouWantToDo(input):
 newString = ""
 alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 for letter in input:
  if letter in alphabet:
   newString += letter
 return newString

yourString = 'MarMaLadE'
print doWhatYouWantToDo(yourString)
print len(doWhatYouWantToDo(yourString)
```